# MySQL and UTC time

Tags: php, mysql, error-log

I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with the connection to my DB.
I have a Linux server which connects to another Linux server that stores the database.
**Once in a while**, the connection seems to be timed out, and the logs are showing "lost connection the mysql at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110'.
I also noticed, that when the error appears, the PHP prints the time in UTC format, and shows incorrect time after "PHP Warning" (but correct one in the start of the line)

> [04 Mar 00:39:07 2013] PHP Warning: [03 Mar 22:39:07 2013 UTC] some error here

when the system works and there are no mysql errors, the log is in the format of -

> [04 Mar 00:39:07 2013] PHP Warning: [04 Mar 00:39:07 2013 IST] some error here

Comment: Correction for local time? You are not fortunate to live in the UK

Comment: so why it happens only once in a while?

Comment: @user31240025 - Stop moving house?!